# Get FullForm content

Tags: output-formatting, expression-manipulation, core-language

For [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/256990/parse-basic-arithmetic-into-an-ast/257014#257014) I need to get `FullForm` as array, string or nested function.
Especially for number expressions.

The best I have achieved is:

```
FullForm@MakeExpression@"1-(4/2)+3*(5+7)"  
Output:
HoldComplete[Plus[1,Times[-1,Times[4,Power[2,-1]]],Times[3,Plus[5,7]]]]
```

But I can't extract useful content as list or string. Is it possible?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: ``MakeExpression@"1-(4/2)+3*(5+7)" //. f_[x___] /; ! MemberQ[{List, HoldComplete}, f] :> {f, HoldComplete@x} //. HoldComplete[x__] :> x`` which returns ``{Plus, 1, {Times, -1, {Times, 4, {Power, 2, -1}}}, {Times, 3, {Plus, 5, 7}}}`` ?

Comment: @Domen  Great, thank you! Could you provide it as answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can play around with `ReplaceAll`, although there are probably some more elegant and concise ways so you should wait for more different approaches ...

```
parseExpr[expr_] := 
 MakeExpression@expr //. 
   f_[x___] /; ! MemberQ[{List, HoldComplete}, f] :> {f, 
     HoldComplete@x} //. HoldComplete[x___] :> x

parseExpr["1-(4/2)+3*(5+7)"]
(* {Plus, 1, {Times, -1, {Times, 4, {Power, 2, -1}}}, {Times, 3, {Plus, 5, 7}}} *)
```